# How do I program a logical volume on Mac OS X (possibly using OSXFuse?)

Tags: macos, mount, vfs

I'm writing a MacOSX application that requires a logical VFS to be presented to the user. Its files' contents are derived from the files stored on the native filesystem, but its file hierarchy and organisation (basically, the directories) are independent from the native file system.

I've seen two instances of this in the wild, really:

1. I've come upon [Disk Drill](http://www.cleverfiles.com/), neat piece of software that lets you scan a hard drive for (deleted) files and recover them. They let you mount files found as a VFS before copying any of those files out to a hard drive.
2. [Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) lets the user view the contents of an encrypted 'vault' file after a password challenge by programmatically mounting volume, whose files are the decrypted file contents of the vault.

How do you programmatically mount a VFS whose implementation is given by my userland OSX application? I looked at [OSXFuse](http://osxfuse.github.io/) and the front page at least seems to say it can do what I want. I'm targeting Mountain Lion or higher.

If any SO users can shine more light on this matter I'd highly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you've answered your own question. Have you tried using OSXFuse?

Comment: Yeah I was just typing out loud as I did more and more research. I haven't tried using OSXFuse yet, so am still hoping for clarity at this stage.

Comment: truecrypt is using `hdiutil` command in background for mounting the files.